# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpmysimplelogin\loginproc.php on line 15

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, xampp

```
<?php
session_start();
include('config.inc');

$login = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE (username = '" .     mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['username']) . ['password']) and mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['password']) . "');

if (mysql_num_rows($login) == 1){
$_SESSION('username') = $_POST('username');
header('Location: index.html');
}

else{
header('Location: index.php');
}
?>
```

In this code I'm getting "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpmysimplelogin\loginproc.php on line 15" this error. Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have an unmatched " on line 5 toward the end of the line.

Comment: I count at least 5 errors, and there might even be more. Confusing `(` with `[` at least two places, quotes being misused and wrong concatenating of strings. I suggest you use an editor with syntax-highlighting, that will help you.

Comment: Hey man, Thanks, I'm new but need to fix it. Could you help me out?